# Using Limits to Determine Asymptotic Relationship

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

Let's say we have $3^{4n}$ and $4^{3n}$. With the note of  [The Asymptotic Cheat Sheet from MIT](http://web.mit.edu/broder/Public/asymptotics-cheatsheet.pdf).

We should first calculate the lim n->infinity   $3^{4n}$/$4^{3n}$. and it result is $\infty$.

In the we have

```
lim n→∞ f(n)/g(n) != 0,∞  ⇒  f=Θ(g)   Note 1
```

and

```
lim n→∞  f(n)/g(n)=∞     ⇒ f=ω(g)   Note 2
```

My questions is:
Given that f(n) is $3^{4n}$ and g(n) is  $4^{3n}$ in this case, which "case" should we apply ?
How should one read Note 1 correctly ? Does it mean  "lim n→∞ f(n)/g(n) not equal to 0, but equal to infinity? then f=Θ(g) " Or
"lim n→∞ f(n)/g(n) not equal to 0 and not equal to infinity, then f=Θ(g)?

Also if f(n) = $\theta $ g(n)? doesn't that already mean f(n) = $O$ g(n)?
if so, then note 1 should read as
"lim n→∞ f(n)/g(n) not equal to 0 and not equal to infinity, then f=Θ(g)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing $3^4=81$ and $4^3=64$, we have $f(n)=81^n$ and $g(n)=64^n$. Using this we obtain:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{81}{64}\right)^n=+\infty$$
so you have your "Note 2". By definition last limit mean $\forall C>0$ we have  $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\forall n>N$ holds $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \geqslant C$ so we have $f\in \Omega(g)$.

For further let's assume, that we have positive functions and $g$ have not $0$s subsequence.

Following question. Your "note 1" means that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ is not $0$ and is not $\infty$, but equals to some number between them.

And last. Suppose $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=A>0$. This means, that $A-\varepsilon<\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} < A+\varepsilon$, for appropriate $n$, and so we can conclude $f \in \Theta(g)$.